# difference between an arithmetic mean and n Arithmetic mean

Tags: linear-algebra

I have not clear visualization of Arithmetic means' concept. What is the application of this. And what is meant by **an arithmetic mean** and **n Arithmetic mean**.

Is the term of sequence and arithmetic mean is same...?

Comment: What? It does not make any difference whether the A is upper case or lower case here. Is there a typo in the question?

Comment: A.Ms and n A.M's

Comment: here n show the number of A.Ms.

Comment: The arithmetic mean of the numbers $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_q$ is $(1/q)(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_q)$. It's not the same as "sequence". The rest of your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Arithmetic mean (AM) of two numbers $a$ and $b$ is just the average of the two numbers defined by $\frac{a+b}{2}$.

But when you are asked to find $n$ AM's between $a$ and $b$, it means to find a sequence of numbers $\{a_1, \dots , a_n\}$ such that $a,a_1, \dots,a_n,b$ are in arithmetic progression. To find them, lets use the well known formula for AP. Here $b$ is the $(n+2)^{th}$ term of the AP and hence $b = a + (n+2-1)d$ or $d = \frac{b-a}{n+1}$.

Now we can write $a_1 = a+d$, $a_2 = a+2d$ and in general $a_k = a +kd $ where $d = \frac{b-a}{n+1}$

Comment: thanks Sandeep Thilakan. that is what i wanted to know.